# Can i build stock AOSP/Lineage OS apps on Android Studio?

Tags: android, build, apk, android-build

i have android phone, i wanna rebuild stock AOSP/Lineage app by name "Settings", i wanna add any functions. I'm download settings app source code from Lineage OS Github, and import this code on android studio. Android studio gives out many errors. I have Mac OS X 10.12 and build android with stock apps is difficult task.

Comment: You don't build AOSP with Android Studio. Lineage already has step by step instructions [e.g. Nexus 6](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/shamu/build) for [supported devices](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/)

Comment: i wanna build AOSP App, not ROM

Answer (score 0):

You can't build Settings app separately, you can only build it with AOSP and even after building Settings app with AOSP you will not be able to run or replace it with existing Settings app on any Android Device because you need to sign it with the platform signing keys.

So it is only possible to build it with AOSP and only possible to run it with your custom ROM.